# Bower install requiring multiple logins on cli

Tags: git, bower

I am feeling more comfortable using composer. In my dependencies block, I have packages from private and public packages. So with the appropiate URLs, I can download the packages from both locations. But I have a problem when there are multiple packages from private locations.

My dependencies block:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "4.5.3",
    "datatbles": "http://git.<domain>.app.br/JavascripWidgets/datatables.git",
    "dropzone": "^5.9.3",
    "fontawesome": "4.7.0",
    "metismenu": "3.0.6",
    "mousetrap": "1.6.5",
    "sliderTelepatic": "https://git.<domain>.com.br/bower/sliderTelepatic.git"
  }
```

When I run `bower install`, during the install, bower require authentication for the git repos, but it seems that multiple promts are open at the same time and the inputs overwrite each other.

```
bower not-cached    http://git.<domain>.app.br/JavascripWidgets/datatables.git#*
bower resolve       http://git.<domain>.app.br/JavascripWidgets/datatables.git#*
bower not-cached    https://git.<domain>.com.br/bower/sliderTelepatic.git#*
bower resolve       https://git.<domain>.com.br/bower/sliderTelepatic.git#*
Username for 'https://git.<domain>.app.br': Username for 'https://git.<domain>.com.br':thisIsUsername
Password for 'https://thisIsUsername@git.<domain>.app.br': Password for 'https://thisIsPassword@git:<domain>.com.br':
```

Is there a reason to the overlapping prompts? Any solution?

Maybe a way to cache the authentication?

Use other package manager?

Thanks!